# "sort < example.txt" vs just "sort example.txt" in gitbash is the same?

Tags: git-bash

haven't been able to get a clear answer on what the difference is between using the "<" sign in the sort command in gitBash, the terminal output is the same?

Comment: Do you need any additional help?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little simplistic explanation and I hope it helps.

Let's say your specialty is to sort a deck of playing cards.

`sort < example.txt` is the equivalent of me telling you: Victor, here are a deck of cards. Can you sort it, please? I am giving you the deck of cards.

`sort example.txt` is the equivalent of me telling you, Victor, the deck of playing cards are on the table. Can you sort it, please? I am telling you where the deck of cards are and you can pick them up yourself.

In the first example of `sort < example.txt`, the `<` stands for Standard Input or STDIN. The command `sort` gets the input from the OS. That input happens to be data from example.txt and sort is asked to act upon that data.

In the second example of `sort example.txt`, the command is told where the file containing the data is so that it can act upon it.

There's a command called `strace` that can read the interaction of between processes. You can run `strace sort < example.txt` and `strace sort example.txt` to see what's happening under the hood.

**Difference in execve**

```sh
strace sort < test.txt 
execve("/usr/bin/sort", ["sort"], 0x7ffdc8246ba0 /* 21 vars */) = 0

vs

strace sort test.txt 
execve("/usr/bin/sort", ["sort", "test.txt"], 0x7ffc8bb4ed18 /* 21 vars */) = 0
```

execve() executes the program pointed to by filename, which is `sort`, which resides under /usr/bin. In the first example, sort is the only argument on the command line. In the second example, there are 2 arguments: sort and the filename sort should act upon as indicated by `["sort", "test.txt"]`.

**File reading differences**

[image]

Left side is the output from `sort < example.txt` and right side is the output from `sort example.txt`. I used the file test.txt instead of example.txt. Notice that `sort example.txt` calls functions like stat, geteuid, getuid and access to get information about the file and permissions because we ask sort to act on the file; so, it does some checks on the file.

If you were asked to pick the deck of cards from the cabinet, you'd find the cabinet, open it, look for the deck of cards etc. before sorting them. The same concept exists for `sort example.txt`.

**More file related differences**

[image]

As you analyze strace's output a bit more, you'll start seeing that differences in `read()`. Left side shows `read(0, "hello\nworld\n", 4096)` where zero is the file descriptor (FD). Zero (FD) is Standard Input or STDIN. Right side shows `read(3, "hello\nworld\n", 4096)`. 3 is a file number or file descriptor that the system gave the file temporarily when reading it.

That shows you how `sort example.txt` deals with files. Again, this explanation is simplistic. There's more going on that others can chime in. Just know that I may have sacrificed accuracy in favor of ease of understanding in this answer.

You'll also notice `write(1, ...`. 1 is a file descriptor that stands for Standard Output or STDOUT. Standard Output appears on the screen. That is - the output that sort generates, which you can see from the terminal is standard output.

You can learn about these individual terms like stdin, stdout, file descriptors, strace, etc. at your convenience.